# Looking for a story where people download their consciousnesses into bodies

Tags: story-identification

I have been looking for a story where people download themselves into clones (somewhat like *Ghost in the Shell*) for travel through space and a poor girl finds one in the river (she doesn't know what it is) and the person downloads in to her.  All I can remember of the cover is that it's red.

Comment: And before anyone downvotes for spelling- sadly, that is the [plural form of consciousness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Language/2007_February_3).

Comment: Side-wonder- scientific community makes plural terms happen/establish with cl**orides and p*nes, but for an already-too-long word?  WTF.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like [Robert Venditti's Surrogates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Surrogates) a little.

> In the year 2054, people use surrogates (humanoid remote control vehicles) to interact with each other (telepresence). In Central Georgia Metropolis, Lt. Harvey Greer investigates the destruction of two surrogates. Greer soon discovers a mysterious figure, which he nicknames “Steeplejack”, plots to permanently disable all surrogates in an effort to eliminate people's dependence on them. Greer considers the anti-surrogate religious leader named “The Prophet” a suspect, but The Prophet is later killed by Steeplejack. Similar to Steeplejack and The Prophet, Greer feels people have become too reliant on surrogates for superficial reasons. Greer chooses to work the investigation in person after Steeplejack destroys Greer's surrogate.

.

> Greer later discovers Steeplejack is a surrogate controlled by Lionel Canter, the inventor of the original surrogate. Lionel designed surrogates as a tool for the physically impaired and became dissatisfied with their widespread personal use by the non-impaired. Eventually Lionel/Steeplejack successfully disables surrogates throughout the city. Greer later discovers his wife Margaret, a surrogate-addict, has committed suicide because her attractive-looking surrogate was disabled.

Comment: Can you provide specific points where the novel(s) agree (or disagree) with the few items provided in the question ?